# visual studio 2010 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When I press Ctrl+F5, I get project out of date debug win32.

Yes:

```
Would you like to continue and run the last build? (Yes)

\visual studio 2010\project\test123\debug\test123.exe isi not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

No:

```
Would you like to continue and run the last build? (No)

\visual studio 2010\project\test123\debug\test123.exe isi not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

If I run code I did on my Visual Studio in class, it works perfectly (files are saved in USB).

It's not a syntax error; I am guessing I'm missing some files but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Open your project properties and make sure that your startup path is correct.  VS can't find your exe, so I am assuming that it is not there for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

It mean's Visual Studio can't find your exe file, or the exe doesn't exist. Why not create a new project, c/p all the code, and rebuild?